# Taylor expansion of a matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, noncommutative-algebra, matrix-exponential

Given two non-commuting matrices $X$ and $Y$, consider the following quantity
$$ e^{X+\lambda Y} $$
What is the Taylor series expansion of the above quantity about $\lambda=0$? Note that this is non-trivial since $X$ and $Y$ do not commute and is not simply $e^X(1+\lambda Y+ \lambda^2 Y/2 + \cdots)$.

One way to proceed is perhaps the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula), which expresses the above quantity as an infinite product of matrix exponentials
$$e^{(X+\lambda Y)}= e^{X}~ e^{\lambda Y} ~e^{-\frac{1}{2} \lambda[X,Y]} ~
e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\lambda^2[Y,[X,Y]]+\lambda [X,[X,Y]] )} ~
e^{\frac{-t^4}{24}(\lambda[[[X,Y],X],X] + 3\lambda^2[[[X,Y],X],Y] + 3\lambda^3[[[X,Y],Y],Y]) }\cdots$$
It can be seen that *even* at the first order in $\lambda$ in the Taylor expansion, there are  contributions from each of the exponentials. The question is : can these terms in the Taylor series be written in closed form, order-by-order?

PS : I would eventually be interested in the trace, Tr[$e^{X+\lambda Y}$].

Comment: Equation (5) of this paper
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1704742?class=pdf has the result. Each order has an integral representation.

Answer (score 2):

Your ultimate question about the trace is much easier to answer.

Let $A = (X+\lambda Y)$, then find the differential and gradient of the trace of its exponential.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(\exp(A)) \\
d\phi
 &= \exp(A):dA^T \\
 &= \exp(A):Y^T\,d\lambda \\
 &= {\rm Tr}\big(Y\exp(A)\big)\,d\lambda \\
\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}
 &= {\rm Tr}\big(Y\exp(A)\big) \\
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(Y\exp(X+\lambda Y)\Big) \\
}$$
At $\lambda=0$ this reduces to 
$$\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda} ={\rm Tr}\Big(Y\exp(X)\Big)$$
**NB:** In some of the steps above, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you also write something similar at the second order or for the second derivative?

Comment: Unless your matrices have some kind of special structure that you can take advantage of (e.g. $3\times 3$ skew), you're back to some variant of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff for the higher order derivatives.